# How to load referenced script libraries from a Roslyn script file?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I figured out I cannot load one script library from another easily:

module.csx

```
string SomeFunction() {
   return "something";
}
```

script.csx

```
ExecuteFile("module.csx");
SomeFunction() <-- causes compile error "SomeFunction" does not exist
```

This is because the compiler does not know of module.csx at the time it compiles script.csx afaiu. I can add another script to load the two files from that one, and that will work. However thats not that pretty.

Instead I like to make my scripthost check for a special syntax "load module" within my scripts, and execute those modules before actual script execution.

script.csx

```
// load "module.csx"
SomeFunction()
```

Now, with some basic string handling, I can figure out which modules to load (lines that contains // load ...) and load that files (gist here https://gist.github.com/4147064):

```
foreach(var module in scriptModules) {
   session.ExecuteFile(module);
}
return session.Execute(script)
```

But - since we're talking Roslyn, there should be some nice way to parse the script for the syntax I'm looking for, right?

And it might even exist a way to handle module libraries of code?

Comment: A first version of the whole thing: https://github.com/joeriks/RoslynWebScript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently in Roslyn there is no way to reference another script file.  We are considering moving `#load` from being a host command of the Interactive Window to being a part of the language (like `#r`), but it isn't currently implemented.

As to how to deal with the strings, you could parse it normally, and then look for pre-processor directives that are of an unknown type and delve into the structure that way.

Comment: Thanks, so I will analyze the syntax tree for my own directive (for example #load), and then create a new tree without that directive(s), and execute the new tree? Or should I better use Compilation.Create... instead of Scripting Execute?

Comment: Rewriting the tree and then calling Execute sounds like a reasonable plan.

Answer (score 6):

Support for `#load` in script files has been added as of https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/f1702c.

This functionality will be available in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Answer (score 1):

Include the script:

```
#load "common.csx"
...
```

And configure the *source resolver* when you run the scripts:

```
Script<object> script = CSharpScript.Create(code, ...);
var options = ScriptOptions.Default.WithSourceResolver(new SourceFileResolver(new string[] { }, baseDirectory));
var func = script.WithOptions(options).CreateDelegate()
...
```